# Apache2 with Zend - looking for .htaccess in wrong location

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, .htaccess, ubuntu

I've never encountered this problem before. I've a Zend project set up at /home/ashesh/prog/php/commonfloor.com/listinSearch/ and the index.php file is inside ..listingSearch/html/ and so is the .htaccess file. The DocumentRoot inside apache is also set correctly to /home/ashesh/prog/php/commonfloor.com/listinSearch/html/

(Ubuntu 11.10 i386)

Whenever I try accessing 127.0.0.1 through the browser, it should open the homepage but instead it throws up a 403 Forbidden message saying I don't have permissions to access / on the server.

A quick browse through the apache2/error.log file shows something strange:

```
[Fri Apr 27 11:33:22 2012] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /home/ashesh/prog/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

Can anyone help? I'm pretty clueless about this and I'm sure it's not a huge fix.

Comment: check the permissions on .htaccess using ls -l .htaccess , and see if it has appropriate permissions

Comment: Doesn't look like Apache is looking in the right document root. If using VHosts, how is yours configured?

Comment: .htaccess permissions: -rwxr-xr-x

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

 DocumentRoot /home/ashesh/prog/php/commonfloor.com/listingSearch/html/

 <Directory />
  ...
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Same error if you browse to http://127.0.0.1/index.php? [Not suggesting that the app require that; just as diagnostic info. Maybe you have indexes disabled (fine) but do not have mod_rewrite enabled (obviously a problem).]

Comment: Yeah, the same result again. The same error message inside error.log.

Comment: Create a blank php file and echo out $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. It's almost definitely the Document root isn't being set correctly

Comment: remove the trailing slash in listingSearch/html/ and change it to  listingSearch/html. Docs suggest that DocumentRoot should not have trailing slash http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot

Answer (score 0):

First check folders permissions. It's seems like you created this dir from root (or other account) and apache cant read it.